# How to add padding to items in Action Column in ExtJS version 7

Tags: css, extjs, extjs7

I have an Action Column using clickable Icons from Font Awesome. My only problem is the icons are too close and the padding config is not working. Does anyone have a solution?

```
{
            header:'Actions',
            dataIndex: 'id', 
            xtype:'actioncolumn',     
            focusableContainer: true,       
            flex: 0.55,
            align: 'center',
            items: [{
                iconCls:'fas fa-pen',
                ariaLabel:'Edit Feedback',
                ariaLabelledBy:'Edit Feedback',
                tooltip: 'Edit',
                
                handler:'onEdit'
            },
            {
                id: Ext7.id() + '_delete',
                itemId: Ext7.id() + '_delete',
                ariaLabel:'Delete Feedback',
                ariaLabelledBy:'Delete Feedback',
                iconCls: 'fas fa-trash',        
                tooltip: 'Delete',
                handler: 'onDelete'
            }
            ]           
}
```

Comment: Configs might not help this. please have a look at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fjt&view/editor

Answer (score 0):

You could add custom css class.

```
.custom-padding {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

and next add to your items.

```
{
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 70,
        items: [{
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-cog custom-padding',
            tooltip: 'Edit',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                alert("Edit " + rec.get('firstname'));
            }
        }, {
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-times custom-padding',
            tooltip: 'Delete',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);

                alert("Terminate " + rec.get('firstname'));
            }
        }]
    }
```